# Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, alternative-proof

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f$ is constant.

> **--Skip this section if you want--**
>
> As this site disallows effortless questions, I'm adding my solution to this problem without going into too much detail:
>
> 1. Suppose $\exists \ r \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(r) \notin \mathbb{N}$. Pick a sequence of rational numbers $\{q_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \to r$. By sequential definition of continuity, $\{f(q_i)\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \to f(r) \implies f(r) \in \mathbb{N}$ (which can be shown using the definition of convergence).
> 2. Now that we know $f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, pick $x, y \in \mathbb{R} \ (x < y)$ and observe that by the intermediate value theorem (IVT), $\exists \ z \in (x,y)$ such that $f(z) \in \text{img}(f) \cap \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{N} \equiv \phi$. This gives us that $f$ is constant.

I request someone to help me solve this without using the definition of sequential continuity or anything taught above the high-school level. More specifically, a proof that uses the IVT and continuity is alright as long as theorems related to introductory real-analysis (despite the tags below) are not involved.

Comment: using $\inf\{q\mid f(q) > n_0\}$ and $\sup \{q \mid f(q) \leqslant n_0\}$ is too high level?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Probably not.

Comment: I think it may be easier (just using the usual $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition with $\epsilon<1$) to show that $f$ must be locally constant on $\Bbb Q$ and hence locally constant on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I have some sort of answer but I don't know if this suits the level you need edit: it had a major flaw

Comment: Since this does not fit your request, I will leave it here. Given an arbitrary $R>0$, then $I_R=\left[-R,R\right]$ is compact and hence $f$ is uniformly continuous over $I_R$. Then there shall be some $\delta_R>0$ such that for any $x,y$ in $I_R$ such that $|x-y|<\delta_R$, we have $\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|<1$. Now since the open intervals of length less than $\delta_R$ covers $I_R$, $f$ is a constant over $I_R\cap \mathbb Q$ and hence over $\mathbb Q$. Then it follows that $f$ is a constant over $\mathbb R$ by the density of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Zhang Thank you for the proof. As you rightly pointed out, it does not satisfy my requirements but I never mind reading or discussing different ideas. (I suspect Ted Shifrin also had the same idea.)

Comment: This constraint seems mightily artificial. Where in the world is any amount of rigorous analysis taught to a significant proportion of students in high school?

Comment: To formally talk about $\mathbb{R}$, we need to have _some_ theorems about it.  Specifically, we need to know $\mathbb{R}$ isn't too big (e.g. the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$... or the Archimedean property), and $\mathbb{R}$ is big enough (e.g. the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ or the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}$).  The IVT _almost_ gets us to the "big enough" but I don't think it goes far enough.  That is, it's not characterizing "continuous" but rather characterizing $\mathbb{R}$ that is the problem with a high school solution.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous,
so there exists $\delta_0>0$, such that when $x,y\in[0,1]$ and $|x-y|<\delta_0$,
we have $$|f(x)-f(y)|<1. \tag{*}$$
Choose $$0=x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_N=1$$
such that $$\max_{1\leq k\leq N}(x_k-x_{k-1})<\delta_0.$$
So  when $x,y\in[x_{k-1},x_k]\cap\mathbb Q$, by $(*)$, we have $f(x)=f(y)$.
i.e. $$f(x)\equiv C_k,\quad \forall x\in[x_{k-1},x_k]\cap\mathbb Q.$$

> For $x_0\in[x_{k-1},x_k]\cap\mathbb{R\setminus Q},$
> choose rational sequence $\{r_n\}\subset[x_{k-1},x_k]$,
> such that $r_n\to x_0(n\to\infty)$, by continuity of $f$,
> $$f(x_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(r_n)=C_k$$

This implies
$$f(x)\equiv C_k,\quad \forall x\in[x_{k-1},x_k].$$
Hence (note that $C_{k}=f(x_k)=C_{k+1},k=1,2,\cdots,N-1$)
$$f(x)\equiv f(0),\quad \forall x\in[0,1].$$

**Similarly**，we can conclude that
$$f(x)\equiv D_n,\quad \forall x\in[n-1,n],n\in\mathbb Z.$$
Due to
$$D_{n}=f(n)=D_{n+1},\quad \forall n\in\mathbb Z,$$
we have
$$f(x)\equiv f(0),\quad \forall x\in\mathbb R.$$

Comment: "The continuity of $f$ implies [...]" feels _a lot_ like begging the question.

Comment: @
Brian Moehring Ok, I give the details!